# Want to exec ADDed binary inside docker container but "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, docker, go

I had my Dockerfile working when I used to copy my source code inside container, then build it and finally launch. Afterwards I decided that it takes too long and now I would like to copy prepared binary into ready docker image.

For the purpose of this question I will just assume this as simple golang server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!!!")
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

Then I compile it using

```
go build  -o webserver *.go
```

Then I want to copy received binary into docker container and launch it

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine

RUN go version

WORKDIR /go/src/golang-baseapp

ADD ./webserver         /go/src/golang-baseapp/
RUN ls -a               /go/src/golang-baseapp/

RUN chmod +x /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver
RUN stat /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver"]
```

The ls command shows that everything is being copied into the container but the CMD step fails and says
`exec /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver: no such file or directory`

My first theory was that this is fault of privileges but using "chmod +x" gave no success. I build and run my image with following commands:

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t sample-image .
docker run sample-image
```

The output:

```
$ docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t sample-image .
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 332B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine
#3 DONE 0.5s

#4 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine@sha256:3ae92bcab3301033767e8c13d401394e53ad2732f770c313a34630193ed009b8
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 33B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [2/7] RUN go version
#6 0.410 go version go1.20.12 linux/amd64
#6 DONE 0.5s

#7 [3/7] WORKDIR /go/src/golang-baseapp
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/7] ADD ./webserver        /go/src/golang-baseapp/
#8 DONE 0.1s

#9 [5/7] RUN ls -a /go/src/golang-baseapp/
#9 0.491 .
#9 0.491 ..
#9 0.491 webserver
#9 DONE 0.6s

#10 [6/7] RUN chmod +x /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver
#10 DONE 0.6s

#11 [7/7] RUN stat /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver
#11 0.529   File: /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver
#11 0.529   Size: 6678922       Blocks: 13048      IO Block: 4096   regular file
#11 0.529 Device: 63h/99d   Inode: 916071      Links: 1
#11 0.529 Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
#11 0.529 Access: 2023-12-10 01:59:03.542679113 +0000
#11 0.529 Modify: 2023-12-10 01:59:03.542679113 +0000
#11 0.529 Change: 2023-12-10 02:00:00.582680528 +0000
#11 DONE 0.6s

#12 exporting to image
#12 exporting layers
#12 exporting layers 0.2s done
#12 writing image sha256:692735852bfbe2de7a94490f9f6143991aea1406c84e6731adff761e23f51ff7 done
#12 naming to docker.io/library/sample-image done
#12 DONE 0.2s
$ docker run sample-image
exec /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver: no such file or directory
```

Any suggestion will be priceless.

EDIT: I simplified this example a little bit and added golang server code, the problem still persists.

Comment: do you have a [MRE], e.g. a github repository you can share?

Comment: @Turing85 I have edited question to make it easily reproducible

Comment: building and running it with `podman` yielded the following results: `{"msg":"exec container process (missing dynamic library?) \`/go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver\`: No such file or directory","level":"error","time":"2023-12-10T02:05:37.668177Z"}`

Comment: In this particular case, setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` before building seems to do the trick: `CGO_ENABLED=0 docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t sample-image .`. We can then use the `docker build` command to build the image. For testing, I recommend publishing the container's port `8080` to the host's port `8080`: `docker run --publish 8080:8080 sample-image`. If we then call `http://localhost:8080`,  we are greeted by the text `Hello World!!!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem diagnosis

Building and running the image with podman gives more information, in particular the container exits with the following error message:

```
{"msg":"exec container process (missing dynamic library?) `/go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver`: No such file or directory","level":"error","time":"2023-12-10T02:05:37.668177Z"}
```

I suspect that this is an artifact of using alpine, in particular of the fact that alpine-linux uses [`musl libc` (`musl.libc.org`)](https://musl.libc.org/). Our system, however, is most likely not running and compiling with `musl libc`. There are several ways to prevent this behaviour. I will highlight two variants.

### Variant 1: build in an alpine-environment

This can - for example - be achieved by a multistage-dockerfile where we build the application in an alpine-based image:

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine as BUILDER
WORKDIR /src/
COPY  main.go .
RUN go build -o webserver *.go

FROM golang:1.20-alpine
RUN go version
WORKDIR /go/src/golang-baseapp
COPY --from=BUILDER \
  /src/webserver \
  /go/src/golang-baseapp/

RUN chmod +x /go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver"]
```

### Variant 2: build a pure go-version of `netgo`

For this, we can build on the host, but add the '-tags netgo` flag to our compilation command:

```
go build -tags net -o webserver *.go
```

At this point, we are independent from any system-libraries. Thus, we can even use a `scratch`-image to run our application:

```
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /app
COPY webserver /app/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/app/webserver" ]
```

### Testing the result

Regardless of what approach we use, we end up with a functional image. To test the image, we should run it, with the container-port `8080` exposed to some host-port. I am choosing host-port `18080` in this example:

```
docker run --publish 18080:8080 --rm sample-image
```

We can now access [`http://localhost:18080`](http://localhost:18080) or use a simple `curl http://localhost:18080` to get the expected response:

```
Hello World!!!
```

### Remarks

I would suggest a few changes.

---

For the compilation of a production-ready application, we should deactivate debug symbols to minimize the final size of the executable:

```
go build \
  -tags netgo \
  -ldflags="-s -w" `# omit symbol table (-s) and DWARF symbol table (-w)` \
  -o webserver \
  *.go
```

This brings the size of the final executable down from ~6.4MB to ~4.4MB

---

For the containerfile, I would suggest using `COPY` instead of `ADD`. I further suggest to use the `--chmod` flag of `COPY` to simplify the containerfile (see the [corresponding `docs.docker.com` section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) for details):

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine

WORKDIR /go/src/golang-baseapp
COPY \
  --chmod=111 \
  ./webserver /go/src/golang-baseapp/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/go/src/golang-baseapp/webserver"]
```

Giving user, group and world executable-bit means that the container can be started with a random user-id (like OpenShift does by default) and it will still work.